# Why (n/2)-1 in heap sort?

Tags: java, heapsort

In heap sort, while rearranging an array in for loop why we need i=n/2-1 and I checked with n/2 also it worked as expected.

```
 // Build heap (rearrange array) 
    for (int i = n / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
        heapify(arr, n, i);
```

Instead, I used like below:

```
// Build heap (rearrange array) 
    for (int i = n / 2; i >= 0; i--) 
        heapify(arr, n, i);
```

Below is the full program,

```
// Java program for implementation of Heap Sort 
public class HeapSort { 
public void sort(int arr[]) 
{ 
    int n = arr.length; 

    // Build heap (rearrange array) 
    for (int i = n / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
        heapify(arr, n, i); 

    // One by one extract an element from heap 
    for (int i=n-1; i>=0; i--) 
    { 
        // Move current root to end 
        int temp = arr[0]; 
        arr[0] = arr[i]; 
        arr[i] = temp; 

        // call max heapify on the reduced heap 
        heapify(arr, i, 0); 
    } 
} 

// To heapify a subtree rooted with node i which is 
// an index in arr[]. n is size of heap 
void heapify(int arr[], int n, int i) 
{ 
    int largest = i; // Initialize largest as root 
    int l = 2*i + 1; // left = 2*i + 1 
    int r = 2*i + 2; // right = 2*i + 2 

    // If left child is larger than root 
    if (l < n && arr[l] > arr[largest]) 
        largest = l; 

    // If right child is larger than largest so far 
    if (r < n && arr[r] > arr[largest]) 
        largest = r; 

    // If largest is not root 
    if (largest != i) 
    { 
        int swap = arr[i]; 
        arr[i] = arr[largest]; 
        arr[largest] = swap; 

        // Recursively heapify the affected sub-tree 
        heapify(arr, n, largest); 
    } 
} 

/* A utility function to print array of size n */
static void printArray(int arr[]) 
{ 
    int n = arr.length; 
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) 
        System.out.print(arr[i]+" "); 
    System.out.println(); 
} 

// Driver program 
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int arr[] = {12, 11, 13, 5, 6, 7}; 
    int n = arr.length; 
    HeapSort ob = new HeapSort(); 
    ob.sort(arr);
    System.out.println("Sorted array");
    printArray(arr); 
} }
```

Comment: And what's your question? Anything not working with the given code?

Comment: I have lot of blogs and all of them used n/2-1, i'm confused why everyone used this instead n/2 and that makes me believe I'm wrong

Comment: Why not write some test cases and see what happens?

Comment: at least help if you have data, Please explain If you know it, that's why I came here,

Comment: I don't have any data at hand, but it should not be too hard for you to craft some

Comment: I don't think running from n/2 is wrong. The algorithms' book CLRS runs the loop from n/2 to 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A complete binary heap of height `h` has `2^h - 1` elements. Of those, elements in the closed range `[0, (2^h)/2-1]` are internal nodes (including the root), and elements in the closed range `[(2^h)/2, 2^h-2]` are leaf nodes. The leaf nodes are already (trivial) heaps. The first element you need to heapify -- because it has a child, which might violate the heap property -- is at index `(2^h)/2-1`.

This property -- that the highest-index internal node is slightly below the halfway point -- extends to incomplete binary heaps as well. Draw out a few heaps and you'll see the pattern.

Comment: Did you mean to say "elements in the closed range [(2^h)/2, 2^h-1] are leaf nodes instead of  [(2^h)/2, 2^h-2] " ?  Can you please clarify how you are calculating height? Based on your explanation and working your formula on some examples it seems you calculate height as levels in the tree and not edges. Example: for a binary tree with nodes = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 you mean the height is 3 but as a convention we count edges as height which will be 2 here.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is based on your implementation for the heap. If the root of the heap starts from index 0 so it should be (n/2 - 1), but if the root of the heap start from index 1 so it should be (n/2)to access the right index in the array.

Answer (score 0):

if n= size of array,then n/2-1 gives all the indexes(when i=n/2-1,i>=0) excluding all leaves.